# how to Compare String Array with ListBox items?

Tags: arrays, string, listbox, c#-3.0, listboxitems

I have

```
string[] parts = {"Product", "Things"};
```

ListBox contains items as

**1.Product 2. Items 3. Things**

I want to match string from parts to items in ListBox.
if it matches I want to select that Item in ListBox.
How to achieve this?? please help  me out

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] parts = { "Product", "Things" };

for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > i && parts[i] == listBox1.Items[i])
    {
        // match
    }
}
```